# #Define array_size is giving me an error in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors

I couldn't find any help online so thats why I'm asking here. Basically I have this code:

```
#define SHEET_SIZE 1024

void GC::initialisation()
{
    GC::sheets[0] = new SHEET_SIZE;
}
```

And it gives this error in my compiler:

> error: expected type-specifier before numeric constant // row 3 where it is defined

> note: in expansion of macro 'SHEET_SIZE' // row 8 where I use it

Note: I use CodeBlocks C++

Note 2:GC is a class, defined in a header and initialisation is one of its methods

Note 3: sheets is of type void*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show where the macro is used.

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Done, also fixed a few things.

Comment: You missed specifying the type of the dynamic allocation on `GC::sheets[0] = new SHEET_SIZE;` for example if sheets is `int** sheets;` you would have `GC::sheets[0] = new int[SHEET_SIZE];` assuming you allocated the other dimension so sheets[0] is an int*

Comment: @drescherjm I tried that and it gives me like 3 other errors. Also its of type void*.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what the program looks like after the pre-processor has replaced the macro with its definition:

```
GC::sheets[0] = new 1024;
```

This statement is syntactically wrong. To fix the bug, you can  remove the line. What to replace it with, I don't know since I don't know what you're trying to do. An allocating new expression looks like this:

```
new type_name;             // single object
new type_name[array_size]; // multiple objects
```

1024 is not name of a type.

> sheets is of type void*

In that case there is another reason for why `GC::sheets[0] = new 1024;` is ill-formed. You may not use the subscript operator on a pointer to void.

---

P.S.

- Don't use `new`. Often, better choice is to use `std::make_unique` instead when you need dynamic allocation.
- Take a moment to consider whether you need dynamic allocation at all.
- Avoid using unnecessary macros. Prefer using variables instead.

Comment: It still gives an error this way. 'sheets' in class 'GC' does not name a type.
I wrote:
new GC::sheets[SHEET_SIZE];

Comment: @IliqnGawrilow Is `GC::sheets` name of a type? The error message says that it's not. Look at what new expression looks like from my question.